# Error in dynamic mapping: Missing type mapping or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, dapper

I have some data classes somthing like this:

```
public class Columns
{
    public string ColumnSource {get; set;}
    public string TargetDb {get; set;}
    public DbType Type {get; set;}
}

public class Table
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList <Column> Columns {get; set;}
}


var dictionariesData = new Table ();
```

I use the **System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder** class to generate a type at run time.

I use Dapper to get the data from a database and generate a variable with the type of the table, for example:

```
var result = connection.Query (typeof (classGerada), "select * from Table");
```

Now I'd like to do a mapping from classGenerated to ClassGenerated2, one difference of the two is once for two columns and all things as columns.

I'm trying to do this using AutoMapper (I accept suggestions for another library).
I am using the following mapping:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize (f => f.CreateMap (targetClass, sourceClass)
.ForMember ("Sequential", m => m.MapFrom ("TableId")));
```

When I run

```
var resultMap = Mapper.Map (result, sourceClass);
```

I have the following error:

> Map configuration of missing type or mapping not supported.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> Type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089]] ->
>   System.Type

***sourceClass is the type generated at runtime from the data dictionary.**

Does anyone know what's wrong? Or what would one do?

Comment: Why generate types at runtime? You can simply use dynamic.

Comment: dynamic isn't enough for me.. hehe
But, if I don't use types at runtime, how I can to do this works using dynamics?

Comment: Dapper can return directly dynamic objects. And you can map those to other types using AM if you want.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu the doubt isn't that! Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Mapping between two types should be much easier than generating types at runtime. Maybe you can isolate the AM part.